# how to auto update AWS windows EC2 instances when updates become available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-systems-manager

I am working with AWS EC2 windows instances and my goal is to associate them with a maintenance window or a patch baseline (I'm not sure which one) to schedule an automation that, when updates for the instance become available it automatically updates itself. I have created a maintenance window for the instances but I think my issue is figuring out how to link up a system to check for updates and run them when they become available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Patch Manager feature of the EC2 Systems Manager service: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html.

There is also a handy getting started blog post available here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/getting-started-with-patch-manager-and-amazon-ec2-systems-manager/

Creating a Maintenance Window is the right first step, this will let you control when you want to do patching of your instances, which instances you want to patch and how you want them to be patched.

To define which instances you want to patch, the easiest way is to tag your instances (e.g. create a tag with the key 'Type' and value 'Patching'), but if you have a reasonably small number of instances and don't launch new instances on a regular basis you can also add them individually, by instance id to the Maintenance Window as a target. If you regularly launch new instances (either manually or as part of an Auto Scaling Group), tagging is convenient as those instances will be picked up automatically for patching.

Once you've added your instances as targets to your maintenance window, the next step is to add a task to the maintenance window. Specifically you want to add the Run Command task 'AWS-RunPatchBaseline' and run that for the target you created above (making sure to set Operation to 'Install').

This completes the minimum steps needed to patch all of your instances whenever the maintenance window runs. Every time the maintenance window runs, the AWS-RunPatchBaseline command will be sent to your instances and all approved patches will be installed and patch compliance reported.

If you want more control over exactly which patches are approved you can also create a custom patch baseline and define specific rules controlling which patches to approve when. If you choose to do so (if not, the default patch baseline is used), you'll also want to set the 'Patch Group' tag on your instances to define which patch baseline to use for which instance. That's described in more detail in the documentation.

Hope this helps, feel free to ping me otherwise.

/Mats